# Change value of input field inside form with 'getElementById'

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="number" id="number1">
<input type="number" id="number2">
<button onclick="dosomething">Click Me</button>
</form>
<script>
function dosomething(){
document.getElementById("number2").value=document.getElementById("number1").value
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS function would change the number inside the second input field of the form, but it's not happenning.

May I know what went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "in Try html", but you've forgotten to invoke your function. So `dosomething` should be `dosomething()`

Answer (score 2):

By default, a `<button>` will submit it's parent `<form>` so your page gets directed to the `action` (since this is empty, likely the page gets `POST`ed to the current URL). You need to update your function to stop this from happening. You also need to execute the function in your onclick handler: in its current form, no function is called. `onclick="foo"` isn't one - `onclick="foo(event)"` is.

HTML:

```
<!-- Pass the event object through to your function -->
<button onclick="dosomething(event)">Click Me</button>
```

Script:

```
function dosomething(e){
     // Stop form submission
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("number2").value=document.getElementById("number1").value
}
```

```js
function dosomething(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("number2").value=document.getElementById("number1").value
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="number" id="number1">
<input type="number" id="number2">
<button onclick="dosomething(event)">Click Me</button>
</form>
<script>

</script>
```

Comment: @NikVarma Your fiddle is set up wrong. You need to select `No wrap - in <head>` for the script so that the function is available globally. [See](https://jsfiddle.net/f3cLu0kk/1/). Also see code snippet in answer

Comment: hehe, thank you, have never checked bez jsfillled gives a notification that you don't have to add a head tag

Comment: thanks, i just can't figure out how many things sounds so simple but i overlook,

Comment: and i have no idea how a newbie like me can even closed to locate these forgotten missing pieces, really thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your button with following line

```
<button onclick="dosomething()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: That is just one side of the problem.